Failed to compile application for the web: Target dart2js failed
I ran the flutter build web command and got an error. I have tried everything.. I ran flutter clean, and flutter pub get and several other commands but it still gives me the error:
Target dart2js failed: ProcessException: Process exited abnormally with exit code 254:
../../Downloads/flutter/bin/cache/dart-sdk/bin/snapshots/dart2js.dart.snapshot: Error: Error when reading
'../../Downloads/flutter/bin/cache/dart-sdk/bin/snapshots/dart2js.dart.snapshot': No such file or directory
  Command: /Users/osuyaalex/Downloads/flutter/bin/cache/dart-sdk/bin/dart --disable-dart-dev
  /Users/osuyaalex/Downloads/flutter/bin/cache/dart-sdk/bin/snapshots/dart2js.dart.snapshot
  --platform-binaries=/Users/osuyaalex/Downloads/flutter/bin/cache/flutter_web_sdk/kernel --invoker=flutter_tool -Ddart.vm.product=true
  -DFLUTTER_WEB_CANVASKIT_URL=https://www.gstatic.com/flutter-canvaskit/edd8546116457bdf1c5bdfb13ecb9463d2bb5ed4/ -DFLUTTER_WEB_AUTO_DETECT=true
  --native-null-assertions --no-source-maps -o /Users/osuyaalex/AndroidStudioProjects/gagna/.dart_tool/flutter_build/5389598c2a36d064db55a8edf57e320f/app.dill
  --packages=.dart_tool/package_config.json --cfe-only
  /Users/osuyaalex/AndroidStudioProjects/gagna/.dart_tool/flutter_build/5389598c2a36d064db55a8edf57e320f/main.dart
#0      RunResult.throwException (package:flutter_tools/src/base/process.dart:125:5)
#1      _DefaultProcessUtils.run (package:flutter_tools/src/base/process.dart:321:19)
<asynchronous suspension>
#2      Dart2JSTarget.build (package:flutter_tools/src/build_system/targets/web.dart:193:5)
<asynchronous suspension>
#3      _BuildInstance._invokeInternal (package:flutter_tools/src/build_system/build_system.dart:875:9)
<asynchronous suspension>
#4      Future.wait.<anonymous closure> (dart:async/future.dart:524:21)
<asynchronous suspension>
#5      _BuildInstance.invokeTarget (package:flutter_tools/src/build_system/build_system.dart:813:32)
<asynchronous suspension>
#6      Future.wait.<anonymous closure> (dart:async/future.dart:524:21)
<asynchronous suspension>
#7      _BuildInstance.invokeTarget (package:flutter_tools/src/build_system/build_system.dart:813:32)
<asynchronous suspension>
#8      FlutterBuildSystem.build (package:flutter_tools/src/build_system/build_system.dart:642:16)
<asynchronous suspension>
#9      WebBuilder.buildWeb (package:flutter_tools/src/web/compile.dart:92:34)
<asynchronous suspension>
#10     BuildWebCommand.runCommand (package:flutter_tools/src/commands/build_web.dart:230:5)
<asynchronous suspension>
#11     FlutterCommand.run.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter_tools/src/runner/flutter_command.dart:1394:27)
<asynchronous suspension>
#12     AppContext.run.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter_tools/src/base/context.dart:153:19)
<asynchronous suspension>
#13     CommandRunner.runCommand (package:args/command_runner.dart:212:13)
<asynchronous suspension>
#14     FlutterCommandRunner.runCommand.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter_tools/src/runner/flutter_command_runner.dart:372:9)
<asynchronous suspension>
#15     AppContext.run.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter_tools/src/base/context.dart:153:19)
<asynchronous suspension>
#16     FlutterCommandRunner.runCommand (package:flutter_tools/src/runner/flutter_command_runner.dart:308:5)
<asynchronous suspension>
#17     run.<anonymous closure>.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter_tools/runner.dart:130:9)
<asynchronous suspension>
#18     AppContext.run.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter_tools/src/base/context.dart:153:19)
<asynchronous suspension>
#19     main (package:flutter_tools/executable.dart:93:3)
<asynchronous suspension>

Compiling lib/main.dart for the Web...                           1,192ms
Error: Failed to compile application for the Web.

Please I need assistance on how to make this work

Try to delete the folder at Downloads/flutter/bin/cache/.
Also share your pubspec.yaml, maybe you're using a package that doesn't support web.

you were right.. deleting the cache and then running flutter doctor, flutter clean and flutter pub get worked perfectly for me

@alex please set my answer as correct if I helped, thanks :)

oooh... no problem @Yaros

Do you already try flutter pub cache clean?

Clear cache
dart pub cache clean or flutter pub cache clean

Clear project
flutter clean

Downlooad dependencies
flutter pub get


